# Delphi DLL not unloading, probably due to still-allocated GDI

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-2007

We wrote a DLL to perform all of our printing functions. It allows us to do print previews, printing, and also generate PDFs.

We now have a particular pattern of use of this DLL, after which the DLL fails to unload properly. The consequence is that when we exit the main program, it disappears but does not terminate, and we have to kill the process manually.

I imagine that the culprit is that some GDI resources are not being properly "closed" (and when I say this, I say it from great depths of ignorance with regard to GDI). We do not handle the GDI resources directly, but rather the GDI resources are employed for us when we use various Delphi components.

Any hints as to how to find and fix such a problem? We used GDIView to confirm that some GID resources remain after we attempt to terminate the program, but I have no idea how to associate those Windows/Kernel handles with the underlying Delphi code.  I can supply GIDView listings at various times during the execution of the program.

Thanks!

Jon (Delphi 2007)

---

I responded to the suggestions that were made, but no one responded to my responses. Eventually, I gave up.  I ended up writing a suicide routine that not only kills my own process, but also every other process with the same name, as a way around the problem. Ridiculous overkill, but I seemed to have no other choice.  I'm using a freeware ProcessInfo facility I found somewhere.

```
procedure KillNamedProcesses(pName : String);
// used to clean up programs that hang as a result of DLLs not unloading
   var
      ProcessInfo : TProcessInfo;
      ProcessName : String;
      i : INTEGER;
      currentPID : cardinal;
   BEGIN
   currentPID := GetCurrentProcessID;
   pName := UpperCase(pName);
   ProcessInfo := TProcessInfo.Create(nil);

   // kill all old processes (not our process)
   for i := 0 to ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses.Count - 1 do begin
      ProcessName := ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses[i].ExeFile;
      IF (UpperCase(ProcessName) <> pName) THEN CONTINUE;
      IF (currentPID <> ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses[i].ProcessID) then
         ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses[i].TerminateProcess;
      END;
   // kill the last one (ourselves)
   for i := 0 to ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses.Count - 1 do begin
      ProcessName := ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses[i].ExeFile;
      IF (UpperCase(ProcessName) <> pName) THEN CONTINUE;
      ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses[i].TerminateProcess;
      END;
   ProcessInfo.Free;
   END; // KillNamedProcess
```

Comment: GDI handles not being released will not cause a DLL (or application) not to properly be unloaded or closed. You're going to have to look elsewhere. Do you use any COM-related resources or interfaces (maybe in the PDF creation you mention)?

Comment: Does your dll make use of gdi+ ?

Comment: Pausing the debugger when the application is at hanged state does not reveal anything?

Comment: Ken - Thanks for your point about GDI handles. I can get the library to hang without generating a PDF, so that is not the issue.  While we do use some other DLLs, I do not believe that we use COM objects.  Is there any definitive way to answer your question?  To put it another way, we do not explicitly install any COM objects with our application (although I guess we might be using some OS COM objects without knowing it)

Comment: mrabat - I assume that GDI+ is a library.  I searched the source code for "GDIPlus" and could not find it

Comment: Sertac - when I pause the debugger during the hang, I end up at ntdll.kiUserApcDispatcher in the CPU pane.  There is no useful stack information.  I am not familiar with using the debugger in this situation: what else can I tell you that would be helpful?

Comment: @jon - When you are responding to a comment, if you don't prefix the SO user name with an '@' the user does not get notified. It's only after you modified your question I was curious about the progress and I saw you have in fact replied the comments. Not that you've missed anything though, at least from me. I was just hoping the call stack would show something useful.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to return GDI resources in order for a process to close. Naturally you ought to return them, but that won't be stopping you from terminating. It sounds very much like you have a deadlock in your DLL unload. And since your DLL fails to unload then you naturally don't get to release all your GDI resources.

Debugging this is going to involve debugging a deadlock. It's rather hard to give general advice on this, and unfortunately you are using an older and less capable version of Delphi. The modern Delphi debugger supports wait chain traversal and make it rather simple to debug deadlocks. I think if I were you I would do some post-mortem debugging when your app is in its deadlocked state. I'd look at the stack traces for all the threads and use that to home in on whatever it is that blocks indefinitely. Use Process Explorer and map2dbg to get hold of meaningful stack traces when the program is in its deadlocked state.

Comment: If GDI is not the underlying problem, what can cause a "deadlock in your DLL unload"?  Where can I read more about that, please?

Comment: When in the deadlocked state, I used Process Explorer to inspect the properties.  There are four threads running: !CreateThread, lHhWindowThread, lExitThread, and ntdll.dlllRtlConvertVListToApiList.  I can provide stack traces for these if you wish (hard to do with a 500 character limit)